# falling asleep or more deeply asleep

Tags: word-choice

> Given sentence:
>
> You sleep more deeply.
>
> Question:
>
> You are ---- asleep.
>
> Possible Answers.
>
> 1.You are **falling asleep.
>
> 2.You are **more deeply asleep.

Which is better to get the same sense as the given sentence?

I prefer sentence 2.

My opinion is that "sleep" is the same in meaning as "are asleep."

Comment: _'sleep'_ ≠ _'are asleep'_. You could say _'sleeping'_ = _'asleep'_.

Comment: Also, Option 2 is incorrect. Option 1 is the right choice.

Comment: I found "are deeply asleep" on N' gram.

Comment: I got Ngram hits for _"I is old"_ and _"I are old"_ too.  That doesn't mean they are grammatically correct.

Comment: @Varun KN .Is the phrase "Are deeply asleep"  ungrammatical?Why? I need one more clear explanation.